# Ansible - How to check netstat port if present?

Tags: ansible

For some reason, I cannot use **wait_for** to check for a particular custom port on mongodb with ansible. Not sure if it is iptables, but I'm not going to change the iptables.

there for instead I though of checking port using netstat

```
    - name: netstat
      shell: /bin/netstat -tln |  grep ":{{ item }} " | sed -e 's/.*\///'
      register:
        netstat_result
      with_items:
        - 27018
      changed_when: false
```

How to I used **fail**

for check if the port is not found?

Comment: did you run this and inspected the `netstat_result` registered variable? looks to me that you have the information you look for in the `stdout` field.

Comment: yes but it is nested...how do I access them ?

Comment: i will run the task you have and come up with an answer, hard to answer from comments :)

Answer (score 3):

here is a way to parse the `results` array. You need to pay attention to the structure of `netstat_result` array (you can add a debug task to print the variable).

Playbook (added a few more ports to run netstat):

```
[ilias@orangehat-29 temp]$ cat test.yml 
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: netstat
    shell: /bin/netstat -tln |  grep ":{{ item }} " | sed -e 's/.*\///'
    register:
      netstat_result
    with_items:
      - 27018
      - 22
      - 80
    changed_when: false


  - name: print result
    debug:
      msg: "for port: {{ item.item }}, netstat stdout was: {{ item.stdout }}"
    with_items:
    - "{{ netstat_result.results }}"

[ilias@orangehat-29 temp]$
```

output:

```
[ilias@orangehat-29 temp]$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [netstat] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
Wednesday 13 March 2019  06:46:53 +0200 (0:00:00.160)       0:00:00.160 ******* 
ok: [localhost] => (item=27018)
ok: [localhost] => (item=22)
ok: [localhost] => (item=80)

TASK [print result] ************************************************************************************************************************************
Wednesday 13 March 2019  06:46:55 +0200 (0:00:01.387)       0:00:01.548 ******* 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'cmd': '/bin/netstat -tln | grep ":27018 " | sed -e \'s/.*\\///\'', 'stdout': '', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'start': '2019-03-13 06:46:54.575733', 'end': '2019-03-13 06:46:54.584105', 'delta': '0:00:00.008372', 'changed': False, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'_raw_params': '/bin/netstat -tln | grep ":27018 " | sed -e \'s/.*\\///\'', '_uses_shell': True, 'warn': True, 'argv': None, 'chdir': None, 'executable': None, 'creates': None, 'removes': None, 'stdin': None}}, '_ansible_parsed': True, 'stdout_lines': [], 'stderr_lines': [], '_ansible_no_log': False, 'failed': False, 'item': 27018, '_ansible_item_result': True, '_ansible_ignore_errors': None, '_ansible_item_label': 27018}) => {
    "msg": "for port: 27018, netstat stdout was: "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'cmd': '/bin/netstat -tln | grep ":22 " | sed -e \'s/.*\\///\'', 'stdout': 'tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     \ntcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     ', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'start': '2019-03-13 06:46:54.898268', 'end': '2019-03-13 06:46:54.906919', 'delta': '0:00:00.008651', 'changed': False, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'_raw_params': '/bin/netstat -tln | grep ":22 " | sed -e \'s/.*\\///\'', '_uses_shell': True, 'warn': True, 'argv': None, 'chdir': None, 'executable': None, 'creates': None, 'removes': None, 'stdin': None}}, '_ansible_parsed': True, 'stdout_lines': ['tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     ', 'tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     '], 'stderr_lines': [], '_ansible_no_log': False, 'failed': False, 'item': 22, '_ansible_item_result': True, '_ansible_ignore_errors': None, '_ansible_item_label': 22}) => {
    "msg": "for port: 22, netstat stdout was: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     \ntcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     "
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'cmd': '/bin/netstat -tln | grep ":80 " | sed -e \'s/.*\\///\'', 'stdout': '', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'start': '2019-03-13 06:46:55.228628', 'end': '2019-03-13 06:46:55.236853', 'delta': '0:00:00.008225', 'changed': False, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'_raw_params': '/bin/netstat -tln | grep ":80 " | sed -e \'s/.*\\///\'', '_uses_shell': True, 'warn': True, 'argv': None, 'chdir': None, 'executable': None, 'creates': None, 'removes': None, 'stdin': None}}, '_ansible_parsed': True, 'stdout_lines': [], 'stderr_lines': [], '_ansible_no_log': False, 'failed': False, 'item': 80, '_ansible_item_result': True, '_ansible_ignore_errors': None, '_ansible_item_label': 80}) => {
    "msg": "for port: 80, netstat stdout was: "
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

Wednesday 13 March 2019  06:46:55 +0200 (0:00:00.226)       0:00:01.775 ******* 
=============================================================================== 
netstat ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.39s
print result ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 0.23s
[ilias@orangehat-29 temp]$
```

hope it helps